# SyntaxError: invalid syntax in dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.6

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./openerp-server", line 2, in <module>
    import openerp
  File "/home/tiny/Desktop/openerp/server/trunk/openerp/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    import cli
  File "/home/tiny/Desktop/openerp/server/trunk/openerp/cli/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from openerp.modules import module
  File "/home/tiny/Desktop/openerp/server/trunk/openerp/modules/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry
  File "/home/tiny/Desktop/openerp/server/trunk/openerp/modules/graph.py", line 32, in <module>
    import openerp.osv as osv
  File "/home/tiny/Desktop/openerp/server/trunk/openerp/osv/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    import osv
  File "/home/tiny/Desktop/openerp/server/trunk/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 22, in <module>
    from openerp.osv.orm import except_orm, Model, TransientModel, AbstractModel
  File "/home/tiny/Desktop/openerp/server/trunk/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 2377
    groupby_dict = {gb['groupby']: gb for gb in annotated_groupbys}
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Dict-comprehensions won't work in Python 2.6.

Comment: Looks like OpenERP trunk **requires** Python 2.7 or newer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create `dict` using

```
dict((gb['groupby'], gb) for gb in annotated_groupbys)
```

Comment: Actually, that's a generator expression, not a list comprehension.

Comment: Removed list comprehension ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Dict comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) were added to the language in version 2.7.

So you need to upgrade to Python 2.7. If you're stuck with 2.6, you could use

```
groupby_dict = dict((gb['groupby'], gb) for gb in annotated_groupbys)
```